# cURL send data after registration

Tags: php, curl

i can't get message with websites avito.ru
My problem what if add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $comment);`
on page will write that write 404 if delete show page . 
Me need send message. help me please
My websites here 2oq.ru/avito/message
error no
My code here

```html
$urlOut = 'https://m.avito.ru/saratov/vakansii/operator_frezerno-gravirovalnogo_stanka_s_chpu_890782585/write';      // Куда данные послать
$urlTo = 'https://www.avito.ru/profile/login?next=%2Fprofile';      // Куда данные послать
$login = 'tytr.trte@mail.ru';                          // Логин
$password = '1qazxsw2';                            // Пароль  
$auth = 'login='.$login.'&password='.$password;    // POST данные
$mes = '2oq.ru Сайт по поиску работы';
$comment = 'comment='.$mes;
$ch = curl_init();                                 // Инициализация сеанса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.avito.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookiefile.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);     // Говорим скрипту, чтобы он следовал за редиректами которые происходят во время авторизации
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:')); // это необходимо, чтобы cURL не высылал заголовок на ожидание
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlOut);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    // получать заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $comment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookiefile.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);     // Говорим скрипту, чтобы он следовал за редиректами которые происходят во время авторизации
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Забираем страниц
curl_close($ch);   
echo $result;
```

Comment: For the second request, you only need change the URL, and POST values

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone how do it ?

Answer (score -1):

Declare,

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

again before sending another curl request.

Comment: Unfortunately this not help

Comment: i now change link show page https://2oq.ru/avito/message.php here example help me please, now script no send message